# View не работает с типом из другого проекта

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня есть список

```
        private ObservableCollection<Player> players = new();

        public ObservableCollection<Player> Players
        {
            get { return players; }
            set
            {
                players = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Players));
            }
        }

        private Player? chosenPlayer;

        public Player? ChosenPlayer
        {
            get => chosenPlayer;
            set
            {
                chosenPlayer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ChosenPlayer));
            }
        }
```

У игрока есть свойство `Won`.

Есть кнопка, меняющая его значение:

```
        private void OnChangeImageButtonClick(object? ignorable)
        {
            ChosenPlayer.Won = 100;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ChosenPlayer));
        }
```

По нажатию на кнопку зависает `ListView` со всеми игроками. То есть при нажатии на любой элемент списка, значение `ChosenPlayer` не меняется. (Если кстати после этого поставить прежнее значение у `Won`, то `ListView` начинает работать как положено). Причем это происходит где-бы я не написал конструкцию типа `ChosenPlayer._ = _`.

Но если менять не напрямую, а через еще одну переменную:

```
        private void OnChangeImageButtonClick(object? ignorable)
        {
            var pl = ChosenPlayer;
            ChosenPlayer = null;
            pl.Won = value;
            ChosenPlayer = pl;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ChosenPlayer));
        }
```

То значение успешно записывается.
Как менять значение напрямую?

Связанный с этими переменными xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ChosenPlayer.Won, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" SelectedItem="{Binding ChosenPlayer}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NickName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

upd.

Класс `Player` у меня объявлен в другом проекте, если продублировать его в vm, то все начинает работать исправно. (Проекты подсоединены, VM с этим классом работает исправно)

Класс `Player`:

```
public class Player
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id"), JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("nickname")]
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("image_name")]
    public string? ImageName { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("description")]
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("group_number")]
    public int? GroupNumber { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("won")]
    public int? Won { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("lose")]
    public int? Lose { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("points")]
    public int? Points { get; set; }

    public Player(string nickName,
                  string? description,
                  string? imageName = null,
                  int? id = null,
                  int? groupNumber = null,
                  int? won = null,
                  int? lose = null,
                  int? points = null)
    {
        Id = id;
        NickName = nickName;
        ImageName = imageName;
        Description = description;
        GroupNumber = groupNumber;
        Won = won;
        Lose = lose;
        Points = points;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj is Player player)
        {
            bool equal = NickName == player.NickName &&
               ImageName == player.ImageName &&
               Description == player.Description &&
               GroupNumber == player.GroupNumber &&
               Won == player.Won &&
               Lose == player.Lose &&
               Points == player.Points;
            if (player?.Id != null)
            {
                equal &= player.Id == Id;
            }
            return equal;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(Id, NickName, ImageName, Description, GroupNumber, Won, Lose, Points);
    }
}
```

Как можно View подружить с объектами из другой библиотеки?

Comment: в сеттер `ChosenPlayer` добавьте `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedImagePath));` и вообще, чем у вас OnPropertyUpdated и OnPropertyChanged отличаются? Покажите эти методы. Глянул в репу, там вообще нет кода, который вы здесь показали.

Comment: Я почистил тут код от лишнего. Попробую поставить сеттер, как вы и сказали, отпишусь чуть позже. OnPropertyChanged это то же самое, что и OnPropertyUpdated, я опечатался.

Comment: upd. ко сожалению, это не помогло. Все так же виснет.

Comment: Сейчас перефразирую вопрос

Comment: Зависает - это когда не реагирует на все действия, нельзя даже выбрать. Когда выбираете, но нет нужной логики это трудно назвать "зависает". Да и зависнуть может только окно целиком, а не один контрол. Далее `Значение не меняется` - как поняли? Выводили на экран, или отладка? Если на экран, то у `Won` есть `INPC`? На Git вот нет, с чего тогда ему обновляться? А вообще, откройте студию, создайте там чистый WPF проект, без единой лишней строчки, и на нем воспроизведите данную проблему, полученный код сюда, в вопрос. Это зовется "Минимальный, самодостаточный пример, который мы можем воспроизвести

Comment: Зависаем в смысле не переключается. На мышку реагирует, но когда кликнешь на другой элемент, то у тебя будет просто два выбранных элемента.

Comment: "Зависает" и "не переключается" - это два совершенно разных понятия, о чем я и написал выше. В любом случае, делайте минимальный, самодостаточный пример, который воспроизведет данную проблему. Тот код, что в вопросе, я не думаю, что он является виновником, ибо в вопросе лишь несколько свойств и небольшая логика по изменению их, не более. И да, повторю, не забываем про INPC, в вашем вопросе на данный момент одна проблема может быть - `Won` не меняется в UI, но меняется в коде, ибо у этого свойства нет INPC.

Comment: Так, я понял, что именно вызывает проблему. У меня `Player` это тип из другого проекта, если использую тип, объявленный локально в vm, то все работает исправно. В чем может быть проблема? Класс дописал в вопросе.

Comment: INPC есть, дело судя по всему именно в том, что `Player` находится в другом пространстве имен, в библиотеке с объектами api. Как можно View подружить с объектами из другой библиотеки?

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь, проблема решена.

Comment: Я до сих пор не вижу INPC у `Won`... Ну да ладно, считаете, что решили, ваше право)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена!

Проблема: `ListView<Player>` переставал работать после смены значения свойства любого элемента.
Решение: В `Player` была переопределена `GetHashCode()`, убрав переопределение все заработало.